# Converting X_T to STL using c++

Tags: c++, cad

I am new in c++ and c language is the only one I know.

What I have is a program that read X_T files and export these to one STL file. It is made of C++ and visual studio and works well. My senior made this.
Now I want to convert multiple X_T files to the same number of STL files. For example, three X_T files -> three STL files, each file have same modeling object of its original file.

Is this possible? If it is, can you guys recommend some books or some reference similar to this function.

Thank you.

Comment: The languages are similar enough that one should be able to extend the functionality to do what you want to do. However, it's hard to suggest anything concrete without seeing the current code.

Comment: You could possible write a [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) to send multiple files to your program one at a time?

Comment: As far as books to recommend go, we keep a [list of the good ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) here on SO.

Comment: @RSahu The move from C to C++ can be quite tough *although* they seem quite similar. I totally agree with your statement about providing code.